# How apply AMP on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, multistore, frontend, magento2.1.6

How can I apply the [Google AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/) on my Magento 2 store without using a paid module?

Comment: Which component you need to implement?
https://www.ampproject.org/learn/overview/

Comment: To implement AMP doesn't just add some components, it's necessary to create a new theme using all necessary components.

Comment: extension is available for it. https://store.plumrocket.com/accelerated-mobile-pages-magento2-extension.html

Comment: Thanks but as I reported I want "without using a paid module"